# How to deal with accent problems using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I'm try to extract the text of a html file, but inside of  tag appears the following text:

```
<h3>Café<h3>
```

and when extract the text using the following code :

```
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("some XPath").InnerText;
```

I get this string "CafÃ©direct" . How could fix this ?

Comment: How do you load the document initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer now, working I detect the way to do , here go :

```
htmlDocument.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

By default the encoding is System.Text.Encoding.Default with UTF-8 the accents are permitted

Comment: Hmm, I've tried this solution and it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this here, basically you can ask HtmlAgilityPack to detect encoding of the HTML document.

[HTMLAgilityPack Asp.net C# Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313578/htmlagilitypack-asp-net-c-sharp-error-handling/18314400#18314400)