# HTMLAgilityPack Asp.net C# Error Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, html-agility-pack

```
    Uri url3 = new Uri("http://www.bigpara.com/borsa/gunun-ozeti/");
    WebClient client3 = new WebClient();
    string html3 = client3.DownloadString(url3);
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dokuman3 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    dokuman3.LoadHtml(html3);
```

Hi everyone, I wanna ask you something about `htmlagilitypack` error handling.

While at url3 adresses "http://www.bigpara.com/borsa/gunun-ozeti/" is refreshing itself in my site is  give error message.

Error Message is :

> System.NullReferenceException and the remote server isn't resolved

what am I supposed to do ? 
and the next question is

Encoding problem
how to `**encoding(UTF-8)**` formatted strings.
special characters doesn't show normally.
How am I prevent this errors ?
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Can't reproduce the exception with the code you provide.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer part of the problem, one with the encoding. As I could not duplicate the issue with loading the HTML.

If you use the HtmlWeb object it will allow you to specify extra parameters for parsing the HTML, one used here is AutoDetectEncoding.

```
Uri url3 = new Uri("http://www.bigpara.com/borsa/gunun-ozeti/");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
web.AutoDetectEncoding = true;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument dokuman3 = web.Load(url3.AbsoluteUri);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah dude it's works thank you, after this i have first part of the problem.

Comment: You can get HtmlAgilityPack code and run it under debugger to see, exactly where you get exception. If this answers ur (part of) question may be you'd like to upvote the answer :-)

Comment: Sorry Sameer, I'm new. Vote Up Reuires 15 reputation warning! :)

but thanks a lot. 

By the way, exception is SystemNullReferenceException. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That's OK. Don't know why you are getting the NullReference exception! I'm pretty certain the reason is something else. Do get HtmlAgility source and turn on 'Break when Exception is thrown' from Debug->Exceptions menu. so you where exactly the exception is thrown.